# Unificar Array Multidimensional em apenas 1 array em PHP

Tags: php, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

É possível transformar um array Multidimensional em apenas 1 (um) array em php? Como seria o processo para se fazer isso?

Na imagem abaixo, preciso transformar o array do lado esquerdo para que os registros fiquem igual o do lado direito, tentei com o array_merge porém não funciona, alguém sabe de outra maneira?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é possível porque o *PHP* não aceita um *array* com dois ou mais índices iguais.

Comment: E se alterasse os nome dos índices para que não fiquei iguais, tipo id1, id2, id3, etc... Seria possível assim?

Comment: Qual a razão de unir os arrays? Ao meu ver, só estará dificultando a manipulação dele.

Comment: @JorgitodaSilvaPaiva Sim, é possível, basta usar um `foreach` para percorrer o primeiro *array* e ir criando um novo array com os valores.

Comment: A razão de unir os arrays será para unir um array que sempre retornará 4 linhas de registros de uma consulta do banco a outro array que haverá os demais dados em apenas uma linha e unir tudo para ficar em apenas uma linha, ficou claro a ideia?
Eu tentei fazer isso com o foreach porém não deu certo.

Comment: @Valdeir Psr se tiver como demonstrar a estrutura desse foreach eu agradeço.